# Load balancer PublicIPReferencedByMultipleIPConfigs error on restart

Tags: azure-container-service

Following along from the [Use a static IP address with the Azure Container Service (AKS) load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip) documentation I have created a static IP and assigned it to the load balancer. This worked fine on the initial run, but now I am getting the following error and the external ip for my load balancer is stuck `<pending>` (personal info omitted):

> Failed to ensure load balancer for service default/[...]: network.LoadBalancersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="PublicIPReferencedByMultipleIPConfigs" Message="Public ip address /subscriptions/[...]/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/[PublicIPName] is referenced by multiple ipconfigs in resource

As far as I can tell, this isn't referenced by multiple configs - just the load balancer service that I'm trying to run. Removing the `loadBalancerIP` option from my `yaml` file allows this to work but then I don't think the server address is static - which is not ideal for the applications trying to communicate with this container

Is this supposed to be happening? Is there a way to configure this so that the same IP can be reused after the container restarts?

Comment: Check in the Azure Load Balancer the "Outbound rules" or other rules and make sure you are not using the IP for something else already. It happened to me that because of not knowing what exactly "--load-balancer-outbound-ips" was for, I was trying to set this parameter and then in the loadBalancerIP setting the same public IP again. Actually I didn't need to use "--load-balancer-outbound-ips". Maybe this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as this issue appears to still be present, for anyone else stumbling upon this issue it seems that the Azure load balancer resource itself may be taking the first configured static IP address.

[GitHub issue response](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10816#issuecomment-400851710):

> the first public IP address created is used for egress traffic

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress#egress-traffic-overview):

> Once a Kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer is created, agent nodes are added to an Azure Load Balancer pool. For outbound flow, Azure translates it to the first public IP address configured on the load balancer.

As far as I can tell, once you provision an IP address and configure an AKS load balancer to use it, that IP gets picked up by the provisioned load balancer resource in Azure. My best guess is that when Kubernetes attempts to provision a new load balancer with the same IP address, if the previous Azure load balancer still exists the IP config will fail as it's still in use.

Workaround was to provision an extra static IP (one specifically for the Azure load balancer resource, and one for the actual AKS load balancer service) to avoid conflicts. It's obviously not ideal but it solves the issue...